# Symfony 1.4 (FORMS) is it possible to set value attribute by sfWidgetFormInputText

Tags: forms, symfony1, input, symfony-1.4

I want to predefine the TEXT-INPUT field - attribute VALUE. Is it possible to do that by sfWidgetFormInputText of other option in the **setup** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation#chapter_01_sub_defining_default_values_for_fields).

```
class ContactForm extends BaseForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    // ...

    $this->setDefault('email', 'Your Email Here');

    $this->setDefaults(array('email' => 'Your Email Here', 'name' => 'Your Name Here'));
  }
}
```